# Make an old network printer findable via AirPrint

Tags: network-printer

I have a few Brother MFC-9970CDW and HL-4570CDWs which are both currently connected to my local network and works fine when printing from a computer, but neither of these support AirPrint.

I'm wondering if there's a way to add the AirPrint functionality via a print server, where the print server would receive the AirPrint document and then forward it over the network.

I know this is possible but have only found options that require the printer be plugged into the print server device via USB, and would like to avoid spending $50-70 on a RPi or similar for each printer. The network printing from a computer works fine, CUPS on a RPi is able to successfully have the printer show up, but it just won't print if it's not a USB connection...

Answer (score 0):

Netgear Genie has a setting to select printers as AirPrint.  Worked on my old Mac Mini connected to a Brother HL2140 USB printer. The app must be running. I can now print from my iPad.

Netgear Genie is software. No additional hardware is needed. Originally posted as a comment in an article on GeekBitZone “How to turn your Mac into an AirPrint server.”  It may work on Windows.

Side note: Genie works for my printer even though the Netgear KB says USB connected printers are not supported. My printer is not listed as a compatible AirPrint printer on Apples website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I guess that's a feature built into Netgear's physical routers? We have Mikrotik equipment though.. sadly choices of reasonably priced 10g capable networking gear still pretty limited.

Comment: It’s software.  I installed Genie on my Mac Mini to give my network printer, connected by USB, AirPrint ability.  Found it in the comments in an article on how to program a Mac for AirPrint support. No additional hardware needed. https://www.geekbitzone.com/posts/macos/airprint/macos-airprint/